# How to change the values in tkinter's OptionMenu?

Tags: python, tkinter

The OptionMenu in tkinter takes any number of parameters for the options in the menu such as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
newMenu = tk.OptionMenu(self, clicked, "A", "B", command=doSomething)
```

Is there a way to update the number of argumenets in OptionMenu so I can go from the above code to this new code:

```
newMenu = tk.OptionMenu(self, clicked, "A", "B", "C", "D", command=doSomething)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [updating-optionmenu-from-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412496)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tk.OptionMenu` has a `Menu` widget in it.

<s>If you want to add some values,you could use [`add_command`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.add_command-method):</s>

```
for i in ["C","D"]:
    newMenu['menu'].add_command(label=i)
```

If you want to remove some values, use [`delete`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.delete-method):

```
newMenu['menu'].delete("0",tk.END) # this will remove all the values
```

---

@acw1668 pointed out a big problem in my code,if you want to also bind command and change the `clicked` variable.

Recommend this([acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) sugguests):

```
for i in ["C", "D"]:
    newMenu['menu'].add_command(label=i, command=tk._setit(clicked, i, doSomething))
```

this also could do but don't recommend:

```
for i in ["C", "D"]:
    newMenu['menu'].add_command(label=i, command=lambda i=i:clicked.set(i) or doSomething(i))
```

Comment: Thank you! I played around with these commands and they make sense now.

Comment: But the newly added item will not call the `doSomething()` and set the `clicked` variable.

Comment: @acw1668 Right,I will try to figure it out.Thanks.

Comment: @ephemeralhappiness You could refuse my answer so that I could delete it because I found a [duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580218/changing-the-options-of-a-optionmenu-when-clicking-a-button),this will be quite detailed.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I implemented your edited code with the additional arguments to the add_command(), but I can't seem to get each new option to have a corresponding command associated with it. Only the label updates upon selection.

Comment: Try `newMenu['menu'].add_command(label=i, command=tk._setit(clicked, i, doSomething))`.

Comment: @ephemeralhappiness acw1668 comment also could work.

Comment: @acw1668 You could consider to post it as an answer,sir.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thank you as well! Now I know how to use add_command functionalities in a tkinter method.